# How to use like condition with multiple values in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, like-keyword

I need to filter out records based on some text matching in nvarchar(1000) column.
Table has more than 400 thousands records and growing. For now, I am using Like condition:-

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_01
WHERE
    Text like '%A1%'
    OR Text like '%B1%'
    OR Text like '%C1%'
    OR Text like '%D1%'
```

Is there any preferred work around?

Comment: You **do know** that using such a `LIKE '%A1%'` operation will definitely disable any index use and thus result in a **guaranteed full table scan** every time...

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_01
WHERE
    Text like '%[A-Z]1%'
```

This will check if the texts contains A1, B1, C1, D1, ...

Reference to using the [Like Condition in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: I have a feeling you've taken the sample code given a bit too literally.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli ... Perhaps I have but all OP mentioned was a "preferred workaround"  This is clearly one way.  If it was performance then FullText Indicies could be useful.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following if you know the exact position of your sub string:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_01
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(Text,1,2) in ('B1','C1','D1')
```

Comment: After some research, LIKE() seems to be better performing than SUBSTRING().

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at **LIKE** on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

You could reduce the number filters by combining more details into a single **LIKE** clause.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_01
WHERE
    Text like '%[ABCD]1%'
```

Comment: I have a feeling you've taken the sample code given a bit too literally.

Comment: Not really. The provided query would just do the same thing as the original. The MSDN link explains why.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I suspect A1, B1, etc. are just dummy placeholders for the real strings being searched for.

Comment: @Joe: So? If it doesn't make sense to @Jango I would expect a comment from him/her.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on that column of your table (that assumes a lot of research on performance and space), then you are probably going to see a big improvement on performance on text matching. You can go to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) to see what `FULLTEXT SEARCH` is
 and this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) to see how to create a `FULLTEXT INDEX`.

Comment: Keep in mind that fulltext indexing is word based while LIKE is searching for a character pattern within a string. As a concrete example, a fulltext search for 'work' would not find the word in 'overworked', but a LIKE clause will.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this so that I could allow two different databases in a filter for the `DatabaseName` column in an SQL Server Profiler Trace Template.

All you can do is fill in the body of a `Like` clause.

Using the reference in [John Hartscock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855842/2449863), I found out that the like clause uses a sort of limited regex pattern.

For the OP's scenario, [MSMS has the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855860/2449863).

Assuming I want databases ABCOne, ABCTwo, and ABCThree, I come up with what is essentially independent whitelists for each character:

```
Like ABC[OTT][NWH][EOR]%
```

Which is easily extensible to any set of strings. It won't be ironclad, that last pattern would also match ABCOwe, ABCTnr, or ABCOneHippotamus, but if you're filtering a limited set of possible values there's a good chance you can make it work.

You could alternatively use the `[^]` operator to present a blacklist of unacceptable characters.