# Combination of 'LIKE' and 'IN' using t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I do this kind of selection:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Street 
WHERE StreetName LIKE IN ('% Main Street', 'foo %')
```

Please don't tell me that I can use `OR` because these actually comes from a query.

Comment: What do you mean with *"comes from a query"* ?

Comment: @ypercube SELECT * FROM Street Where StreetName LIKE IN (SELECT name + '%' from CarStreets Where Streets = 'offroad' ) It's not the best example but I believe u get the point

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no combined `LIKE` and `IN` syntax but you can use `LIKE` to `JOIN` onto your query as below.

```
;WITH Query(Result) As
(
SELECT '% Main Street' UNION ALL
SELECT 'foo %'
)
SELECT DISTINCT s.* 
FROM Street s
JOIN Query q ON StreetName LIKE q.Result
```

Or to use your example in the comments

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* 
FROM Street s
JOIN CarStreets cs ON s.StreetName LIKE cs.name + '%'
WHERE cs.Streets = 'offroad'
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is like telling me to use 'OR' with an other way. I want the conditions to be dynamic based on a query.

Comment: +1 - I was going to suggest a little SQL CLR that takes regexes, and use the regex syntax for multi-like capability.  I've never thought of using LIKE as a join criteria--brilliant.

Comment: @Peter - you might want to spend some time editing your question to be clear.  The question as written doesn't suggest dynamic sql.  Instead, it suggests you want a multi-like scenario. Also, @Martin's solution can be adapted to be very dynamic based on the params - you could do a CSV-Split maneuver to a table valued UDF and join against that.

Comment: I will give it a try. Yes this looks something that might work. But still this looks like a workaround imho.

Comment: ...or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855754/how-to-use-like-condition-with-multiple-values-in-sql-server-2005) among many others!

Comment: @onedaywhen - Ah the penny just dropped on this one! The or is a continuation of [your comment here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408900/sql-server-combining-like-and-in)

Comment: 11 years later this answer is still brilliant

Answer (score 7):

You don't have a lot of choices here.

```
SELECT * FROM Street Where StreetName LIKE '% Main Street' OR StreetName LIKE 'foo %'
```

If this is part of an existing, more complicated query (which is the impression I'm getting), you *could* create a table value function that does the checking for you.

```
SELECT * FROM Street Where StreetName IN (dbo.FindStreetNameFunction('% Main Street|foo %'))
```

I'd recommend using the simplest solution (the first). If this is nested inside a larger, more complicated query, post it and we'll take a look.

Comment: ok I believe that what i'm asking is not possible. Since I don't want to type the `'foo %'` or the `'%Main Street'` since they are dynamic and can change.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar conundrum but due to only needing to match the start of a string, I changed my 'like' to [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as such:

```
SELECT *  
FROM codes  
WHERE SUBSTRING(code, 1, 12) IN ('012316963429', '012315667849')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resort to Dynamic SQL and wrapping up all in a stored procedure.

If you get the LIKE IN param in a string as tokens with a certain separator, like

```
'% Main Street,foo %,Another%Street'
```

first you need to create a function that receives a list of LIKE "tokens" and returns a table of them.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitList]
(
  @list nvarchar(MAX),
  @delim nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @splitTable table 
(       
  value nvarchar(50)
) 
AS BEGIN
  While (Charindex(@delim, @list)>0) Begin 
    Insert Into @splitTable (value)
      Select ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@list, 1, Charindex(@delim, @list)-1))) 
    Set @list = Substring(@list, Charindex(@delim, @list)+len(@delim), len(@list))
  End     
  Insert Into @splitTable (value) Select ltrim(rtrim(@list))
  Return
END
```

Then in the SP you have the following code

```
declare 
  @sql nvarchar(MAX),
  @subWhere nvarchar(MAX)
  @params nvarchar(MAX)

-- prepare the where sub-clause to cover LIKE IN (...)
-- it will actually generate where sub clause StreetName Like option1 or StreetName Like option2 or ...   
set @subWhere = STUFF(
  (
    --(**)
    SELECT ' OR StreetName like ''' + value + '''' FROM SplitList('% Main Street,foo %,Another%Street', ',') 
      FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 4, '')

-- create the dynamic SQL
set @sql ='select * from [Street]
  where 
    (' + @subWhere + ')
    -- and any additional query params here, if needed, like
    AND StreetMinHouseNumber = @minHouseNumber
    AND StreetNumberOfHouses between (@minNumberOfHouses and @maxNumberOfHouses)'

set @params = ' @minHouseNumber nvarchar(5),
  @minNumberOfHouses int,
  @minNumberOfHouses int'     

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params,    
  @minHouseNumber,
  @minNumberOfHouses,
  @minNumberOfHouses
```

Of course, if you have your LIKE IN parameters in another table or you gather it through a query, you can replace that in line (**)

Answer (score 1):

What I did when solving a similar problem was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.* 
FROM Street AS S
JOIN (SELECT value FROM String_Split('% Main Street,foo %', N',')) T 
    ON S.StreetName LIKE T.value;
```

Which is functionally similar to Martin's answer but a more direct answer to the question.

Note: DISTINCT  is used because you might get multiple matches for a single row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can clarify what he is looking for, but I don't know the answer.  I'll use my situation to demonstrate.  I have a table with a column called "Query" that holds SQL queries.  These queries sometimes contain table names from one of my databases.  I need to find all Query rows that contain table names from a particular database.  So, I can use the following code to get the table names:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

I'm trying to use a WHERE IN clause to identify the Query rows that contain the table names I'm interested in:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [DatasourceQuery]
 WHERE Query IN LIKE
(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
)
```

I believe the OP is trying to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way:

First create a table function:

```
create function [splitDelimeter](@str nvarchar(max), @delimeter nvarchar(10)='*')
returns @r table(val nvarchar(max))
as
begin

    declare @x nvarchar(max)=@str
    set @x='<m>'+replace(@x, @delimeter, '</m><m>')+'</m>'

    declare @xx xml=cast(@x as xml)

    insert @r(val)
    SELECT Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') id
    FROM @xx.nodes('/m') Tbl(Col)

    return 
end
```

Then split the search text with your preference delimeter. After that you can do your select with left join as below:

```
  declare @s nvarchar(max)='% Main Street*foo %'

  select a.* from street a
     left join gen.splitDelimeter(@s, '*') b
        on a.streetname like b.val
  where val is not null
```