# SQL Server, combining LIKE and IN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

Is there an easy way to combine `LIKE` and `IN` in one statement in SQL Server, without using a lot of `AND` and `OR`?

e.g. I know in MySQL you can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 REGEXP 'value1|value2|value3'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really.

There is no alternation operator in the `LIKE` pattern syntax. If on 2008 you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   (VALUES ('value1'),
                             ('value2'),
                             ('value3')) Vals(val)
              WHERE  column1 LIKE '%' + val + '%')
```

You can also use Regular Expressions in SQL Server but not natively. You need to enable CLR and install an assembly for this.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but got the following error message 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. Severity 15'

Comment: @200 - I guess you are not on 2008 then. In previous versions something similar is possible with using `SELECT 'value1' UNION ALL SELECT 'value2' UNION ALL SELECT 'value3'` in the derived table definition which is a bit more tedious.

Comment: Thanks Martin. This will do for now :). Wonder why Microsoft doesn't implement an easier way to do this though...

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

Given the following table:

```
--- (a) Test Table
DECLARE @EAV TABLE (
    entity  int,
    attr    varchar(50),
    val     varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @EAV (entity, attr, val) VALUES 
    (1, 'mobileNo', '016-222-9000'),
    (2, 'mobileNo', '016-254-5000'),
    (3, 'mobileNo', '012-378-4550'),
    (4, 'mobileNo', '019-456-2258'),
    (5, 'mobileNo', '017-378-8888'),
    (6, 'mobileNo', '010-111-9999')
```

You can achieve this using the following SQL:

```
--- (b) Code for LIKE ... IN
DECLARE @patterns varchar(100) = '016%, %378%' --- the patterns
SELECT pattern=p.value, x.entity, x.attr, x.val 
    --from Meta.StrSplit(@patterns,',') p
    FROM string_split(@patterns, ',') p
    CROSS APPLY @EAV x
    WHERE x.val like LTRIM(RTRIM(p.value))  --- trim needed to strip off trailing & leading blanks that mess up pattern
```

To provide a complete answer:

```
------------------------------------------
---- Wrap this into a function
------------------------------------------
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.InLike (@string varchar(400), @listPatterns varchar(400))
RETURNS TABLE AS 
RETURN (

    SELECT Pattern=p.Value
    --FROM Meta.StrSplit(@listPatterns, ',') p
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@listPatterns, ',') p
    WHERE @string LIKE p.[Value]
)
GO
```

And here are some usage examples:

```
---- USAGE (a) JOIN
SELECT * 
    FROM @EAV x
    CROSS APPLY dbo.InLike(x.val,'016%, %888%') p


---- USAGE (b) CASE statement
SELECT * 
    , NumberCategory = CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.InLike(x.val,'016%, %888%')) THEN 'Special Numbers'
        ELSE 'Ordinary Numbers'
      END
    FROM @EAV x

    
---- USAGE (c) IF statement
declare @MobileNo varchar(50) = '016-888-0000'
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Meta.InLike (@MobileNo, '016%,%888%'))  
    PRINT @MobileNo + ' is special number'
ELSE PRINT @MobileNo + 'is NOT special number'


---- USAGE (d) WHERE condition
SELECT * FROM @EAV x
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.InLike(x.val,'016%, %888%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to put the search values in a table and build a dynamic SQL to do the work. It is not recommended but sometimes helps...