# Find out if a value exists in a column with a large input values set

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the most effective (and simple) way to find out if a specific column cells of a table contain one of a given values?

To give you some background, I have a list of 1000 ID numbers. They might or might not exist in a "FileName" column of a table "ProcessedFiles" as a part of the filename.

Basically, I need to check which of these 1000 tasks have been processed (i.e. they exist in the table).

The thing that I came with seems very uneffective:

```
SELECT * FROM ProcessedFiles 
WHERE FileName LIKE '%54332423%'
OR FileName LIKE '%234432%'
OR FileName LIKE '%342342%'
...
```

etc

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is there some consistent part of the filename that contains the number , or could it literally be any part of it? eg if the number is `123`, is the filename something structured like `XXX-123-YYY.DAT` or could it be just anywhere like `AB9812356X.DAT`

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @RuslanVeselov - I am using MicrosoftSQL Serwer

Comment: @Bohemian - I cannot be sure, I need to assume that it can be any part of it

Comment: Then IMHO it will perform poorly no matter what you do, and what you have works, so I would leave it at that. If the number could be extracted predictably from the filename, then there is something effective you could have done.

Comment: @Bartosz This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102380/combination-of-like-and-in-using-t-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary table and insert all the Ids in a column. Then you could cross join with the ProcessedFiles table and check for the id in the name with a like:

```
SELECT pf.* 
FROM ProcessedFiles pf,table t
WHERE pf.FileName like '%'+t.Id+'%'
```

I tested the above and it worked on SQL Server.

Comment: And what does the full SQL look like then, including all the insert statements? Roughly the same as OP's query.