# Is it possible to write a case statement when column BEGINS with possible list of values?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to simplify my code and have one line that checks if the values in a column begin with any of the values in a list of possible instead of writing out each condition separately. I believe the issue is the wildcard since no matter what I've tried, the following example piece of code never returns the correct value, NEW_NAME. Is it even possible to use a wildcard with an IN operator? What do I do instead?

```
CASE 
    WHEN COLUMN IN ('AAA%', 'WWW%','XXX%', 'YYY%', 'ZZZ%') 
        THEN NEW_NAME 
        ELSE COLUMN
```

Comment: You cannot do that with `in` you need `like 'AAA%' or like 'XXX%'` etc; Alternatively look for the left(3) characters `in()`

Comment: Please add a tag for the RDBMS.

Comment: T-SQL's `x IN ( a, b, c )`  operator is just shorthand for `( x = a OR x = b OR x = c )` - you can't use it with `LIKE`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination of 'LIKE' and 'IN' using t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102380/combination-of-like-and-in-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Oracle you could write:

```
Case
  when regexp_like(column, '(AAA|WWW|XXX|YYY|ZZZ).*')
    then NEW_NAME
    else COLUMN
End as column
```