# Query to find users

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to write a query to get a list of users  where their fullname is in an attribute named **description**. User names are kept in that attribute in any of the format:-

- LASTNAME Firstname
- LASTNAMEFirstname (without space)
- FirstnameLastname

In such a scenario if I need to search a given list of users(around 100) in that attribute, I have to write query like
`select * from dm_user where UPPER("description") like '%FIRSTUSER_FIRSTNAME%' OR UPPER("description") like '%SECONDUSER_FIRSTNAME%'` and so on..

Is their a way I can do things more simply.I hate writing `*UPPER("description") like*` 100 times.(Please suggest standard sql query).
I  need to run this query on Documentum and MSSQL.

I just want to have something like

{

```
select * from dm_user 
where UPPER("description") 
like IN ('%FIRSTUSER_FIRSTNAME%','%SECONDUSER_FIRSTNAME%');
```

but its not available in documentum}

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855754/how-to-use-like-condition-with-multiple-values-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use use dynamic queries and let SQL Server to write those strings 100 times?

```
--DROP TABLE #User
-- This is an EXAMPLE: keep using your names source
CREATE TABLE #User(Id int, Name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO  #User VALUES (1, 'First')
INSERT INTO  #User VALUES (2, 'Second')
-- ... and so on

DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)
SELECT  @Query = 'SELECT * FROM DM_USER WHERE 1=0' +
        (
            SELECT  '
 OR Description LIKE ' + QUOTENAME('%' + Name + '%', '''')
            FROM    #User
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

PRINT   '@Query = ' + ISNULL(@Query, 'NULL')
EXEC    sp_executesql @Query
```

Result:

```
@Query = SELECT * FROM DM_USER WHERE 1=0
 OR Description LIKE '%First%'
 OR Description LIKE '%Second%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid writing `LIKE` many times, and you're working with MSSQL, take a look at **[temporary tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)** or **[table variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)**.

The general idea would be to put all search terms (firstname - lastname combinations) in a temp table / table variable, and then execute a query which checks whether `dm_user.description` containts at least one of the search terms.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
FROM dm_users AS u, #tmp as t
WHERE dm_users.description LIKE N'%' + t.searchterm + '%'
```

Comment: I m sorry but I dont have  privilege to create anything its just DQL

Comment: It's all dynamic sql. Here's an article describing with examples http://sergeb.com/blog/post/Dynamic-multi-value-SQL-LIKE.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use FreeText Search for MSSQL, but idk how that would handle the names.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to avoid using the the UPPER() syntax all the time you can declare the variable (depending on your DBMS)

```
declare @description varchar(max)
set @description= UPPER('description');

select 
    * 
from 
    dm_user 
where 
    @description like '%FIRSTUSER_FIRSTNAME%' 
    OR @description like '%SECONDUSER_FIRSTNAME%'
```